# how to use a custom action with the intent I use in my service?

Tags: android, android-intent, action, custom-attributes, intentfilter

In my manifest I added in my activity:

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="webradio.disneychannel.ACTION_DIALOG_CLOSE" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</ intent-filter>
```

And in my service I launch :

```
Intent close = new Intent(ACTION_DIALOG_CLOSE);
close.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(close);
```

where `ACTION_DIALOG_CLOSE` is an `String = webradio.disneychannel.ACTION_DIALOG_CLOSE`

But when the activity start, in the resume, `this.getIntent().getAction()` always return null...

Comment: Is your activity already running when the service calls `startActivity()`?

Comment: What you have posted should work fine, would you post more code so we can see what is happening?

Comment: it's possible there is an other instance of this activity in background, this may be the cause?

Comment: If this Intent starts the Activity then the action will be `"webradio.disneychannel.ACTION_DIALOG_CLOSE"`, if you are starting the Activity another way then the action will be different. Without any more code, I just don't know what is happening.